# vite-typescript-ssr-react - No routes matched location

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite, server-side-rendering

I am new to NodeJS and am using this template [vite-typescript-ssr-react](https://github.com/jonluca/vite-typescript-ssr-react/),
when I add routes to the app.tsx file like i would in a react application.

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import AuthPage from "./pages/AuthPage.tsx";
import DashboardPage from "./pages/DashboardPage.tsx";
import { ContextWrapper } from "./context/Context.tsx";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <ContextWrapper>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/auth" element={<AuthPage />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<DashboardPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </ContextWrapper>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I get the following errors:

```
app  | No routes matched location "/" 
app  | No routes matched location "/tailwindcss/components" 
app  | No routes matched location "/tailwindcss/utilities" 
app  | No routes matched location "/tailwindcss/base" 
app  | No routes matched location "/favicon.ico"
```

not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

I created a favicon and put it in the puiblic folder.
Then I injected it into the server rendered html.

First using this function to get the css and the favicon

```
// Get style sheets and favicon from public/css
const getAssets = async () => {
  try {
    // Get the path to the public directory
    const assetPath = resolve("public");

    // Get CSS files
    const cssFiles = await fs.readdir(path.join(assetPath, "css"));
    const cssAssets = cssFiles.map((file) => path.join("css", file));

    // Get the content of CSS files
    const cssContent = await Promise.all(
      cssAssets.map(async (asset) => {
        const content = await fs.readFile(path.join(assetPath, asset), "utf-8");
        return `<style type="text/css">${content}</style>`;
      })
    );

    // Get the favicon
    const faviconPath = path.join(assetPath, "favicon.ico");
    const faviconContent = await fs.readFile(faviconPath, "base64");
    const faviconTag = `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,${faviconContent}" />`;

    // Return the CSS content and favicon tag
    return [...cssContent, faviconTag].join("\n");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error getting style sheets and favicon:", error);
    return "";
  }
};
```

Then

```
const Assets = await getAssets();

const html = template
  .replace(`<!--app-html-->`, appHtml)
  .replace(`<!--head-->`, Assets);
```

The Tailwind requests I got rid off by removing redundant tailwind.css and styles.css. I dont need it, since I have imported all styles in my entry-server and entry-client.

Also I added the following to the SSR route.

```
// Skip SSR rendering for API routes
if (url.startsWith("/api")) {
  return next();
}
```